# Invoke-sqlcmd with scripting variables and function parameters

Tags: sql-server, function, variables, powershell, parameter-passing

I have several tables that need to be periodically cleaned (de-duplicated). I want to create a function I can call and pass in a table name as a parameter. I'm stuck on the appropriate use of back tics (`), quotes (") and parentheses to reference the inline scripting variable ($) I'm trying to pass in as a function parameter.

I have poured over "get-help invoke-sqlcmd -detailed" and tried various combinations with the -Variable options, but with no success.

Can someone help me with the correct syntax?

My stripped down script looks like this -

```
# Define Server
$server = "AHDC389"  
# Define Database
$dbname = "VBP" 
# Define Table
$dbtab = "[FacilityBaseline]"   
# Import SQL svr handler
Import-Module “sqlps” -DisableNameChecking  
# Set env for SQL svr handler
Set-Location SQLSERVER:\SQL\$server\DEFAULT\Databases\$dbname
# Define my SQL query
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT * INTO #Temp FROM `$dbtab; TRUNCATE TABLE `$dbtab; 
INSERT INTO `$dbtab SELECT DISTINCT * FROM  #Temp;"
# Put Query in a Function for reuse
Function DeDup ([string] $dbtab) {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query
}
# Call my Function and pass the Table name I want to dedup.
DeDup $dbtab
```

The errors I'm getting are " Incorrect syntax near '$dbtab' " or " 'dbtab' scripting variable not defined '

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use the backtick. With a backtick, the variable values don't get included in the query string. It will look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * INTO #Temp FROM $dbtab; TRUNCATE TABLE $dbtab; 
INSERT INTO $dbtab SELECT DISTINCT * FROM  #Temp;
```

Without a backtick, the variable values get expanded and the query will look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * INTO #Temp FROM [FacilityBaseline]; TRUNCATE TABLE [FacilityBaseline]; 
INSERT INTO [FacilityBaseline] SELECT DISTINCT * FROM  #Temp;
```

So, the right $query statement will be:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT * INTO #Temp FROM $dbtab; TRUNCATE TABLE $dbtab; 
INSERT INTO $dbtab SELECT DISTINCT * FROM  #Temp;"
```

Comment: Than you. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the backtick before $dbtab is forcing the double-quotes to treat the dollar sign as a literal rather than introducing a variable name.  Drop the backtick and that will work (and substitute the value of $dbtab).